# How to add my custom popup menu item,when i choose the text in other app?

Tags: android

for example,i choose a word in chrome ,and it popup a menu that i can Copy and do some other operation(search, translate).so how can i implement my custom menu item to handle the clip text in other application
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i got it.(it just valid in 6.0+)

you just should edit your manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".search.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/your_menu_item_name"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

then, you can handle the intent and get your text